# Prompt the user to enter 3 strings, each string has 3 characters

Tags: java, arrays, validation, char

I'm very new to Java and have no idea what I'm doing. I am supposed to prompt the user to enter three strings, each string has three characters and the characters will either be an 'a' or an 'b', but I'm really stuck and I don't know what to do, how to validate this conditions. Here is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Array {
    public static void main(String[]args) {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    String strings[]= new String[3];

    System.out.println("Enter the strings: ");

    for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {
        strings[i] = scanner.nextLine();
    }

    char c[] = new char[3];

        if(c.length ==3){

            for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
                c[i] = strings[i].charAt(i);
            }
        } else System.out.println("Error");


    System.out.println("You entered the following strings: ");

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
        System.out.println(strings[i]);
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Please keep in mind that I'm not allowed to use array list.

Comment: What are you stuck with? Does the program run? What results are you getting, and what results are you expecting?

Comment: What exactly is your question? I got what you are trying to do but not able to conclude on the question part

Comment: The program doesn't run, I don't know how to check that strings have 3 characters, because I'm using an array.

Comment: Well the first step is to troubleshoot why it doesn't run. Double check all your opening and closing brackets as a start. You are missing the opening bracket for your last for loop.

Comment: To check if a string has 3 characters, check it with an if statement. Ex: if(str.length()==3)

Comment: But it's an array, I need 3 strings of 3 characters each

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try replacing your main function with something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    String strings[]= new String[3];

    for(int i=0; i<3; i++) //do 3 times
    {
        System.out.println("Enter string: ");

        //get user input
        String input = scanner.nextLine();
        strings[i] = input;

        //check if input is correct size
        if(input.length()!=3){
            System.out.println("Error: input is wrong size; must be size 3");
        }

        //check that the input only consists of 'a' and 'b' characters
        for(int j=0;j<input.length();j++){
            if(input.charAt(j) !='a' && input.charAt(j) != 'b'){
                System.out.println("Error: input contains invalid characters");
                break; //after finding an invalid character, break out of inner loop
            }
        }
    }
    scanner.close(); //close the scanner after it is no longer needed

    System.out.println("You entered the following strings: ");

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        System.out.println(strings[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

add the following code

```
c[i] = strings[i].charAt(i);
if(!(c[i] == 'a' || c[i] == 'b')){
   System.out.println("Error");
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply !

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood right what you want.

1. One important thing I think you should know is that an Array is always starting in position 0, what means that if you declare a new Array[3], it will have 4 positions: `Array[0]`,`Array[1]`,`Array[2]`,`Array[3]`
2. When you loop throw an `Array` I would advice you trying to use this format:

   ```
    for (int i = 0;i < Array.length(); i++){
            do something...
         }
   ```

Like this you will mostly avoid the Problem of getting a `NullPointerException` becasue you give a wrong number of the Long of the `Array`

3. In this part of your code:

   char c[] = new char[3];

   ```
   if(c.length ==3){

       for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
           c[i] = strings[i].charAt(i);
       }
   } else System.out.println("Error");
   ```

The first condition will be always `true`, so you will check then the `Input` of the user in the foor Loop, but never will print the mistake from down.

4. Try this code to check de length of the `Strings` of the `Input`:

   for (int i = 0; i < strings.length(); i++){

   ```
    if(!strings[i].length() == 3){
       System.out.println("Error in String number " + i);
      }
   ```

I haven't got at the moment the possibility of running this code, so it can be there is something wrong, but I hope it can help a bit at least. Greets.

Comment: I don't know why is not formatting the last code block, please if someone could edit it to correct, I can't get it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply !

Answer (score 0):

add one more for loop to traverse each string.

```
if(c.length ==3){
            System.out.println(c.length);
            for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {

                for(int j = 0; j < c.length; j++)
                {

                    if(!(c[i] == 'a' || c[i] == 'b')){
                           System.out.println("Error");
                         }
                    else
                        c[i] = strings[i].charAt(j);
                }
                System.out.println(c[i]);
            }
        } else System.out.println("Error");
```

say you have three string 
aba
bba
aaa

first loop will traverse aba,bba,aaa

second loop will traverse and check the weather the each character of each  string contains a or b